# Use one class based view for both List and Retrieve Rest API

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I currently have two different class based views for detailing a specific object and for listing all objects:

```
class StatusList(ListAPIView):
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)
    serializer_class = serializers.StatusSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = helperfunctions.getObjects(self.request.user, models.Status)
        return queryset


class StatusDetail(RetrieveAPIView):
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)
    serializer_class = serializers.StatusSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = helperfunctions.getObjects(self.request.user, models.Status)
        return queryset
```

Note that helperfunctions.getObjects() simply returns the objects that share the same establishment with the user, so that they can't see statuses that they shouldn't.

What I want to know is whether there's an option to use only one class based view for both StatusDetail and StatusList, which would automatically know that when it gets a pk in the get request it returns the appropriate object, and when it doesn't, it should return the whole list of objects.

Thanks for any help :)

Comment: you might consider using ModelViewSet

Comment: In fact this is *exactly* what viewsets are for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [viewsets](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/), like so
:

```
from rest_framework import viewsets, permissions, mixins    
class StatusDetail(mixins.ListModelMixin, #specify wanted mixins
                       mixins.RetrieveModelMixin,
                       viewsets.GenericViewSet): 
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)
    serializer_class = serializers.StatusSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = helperfunctions.getObjects(self.request.user, models.Status)
        return queryset
```

Answer (score 4):

Viewsets has `ReadOnlyModelViewSet` and allows only `retrieve` and `list`.

```
class StatusDetail(viewsets.ReadOnlyModelViewSet): 
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)
    serializer_class = serializers.StatusSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = helperfunctions.getObjects(self.request.user, models.Status)
        return queryset
```

Answer (score 1):

Okay so I got to this awesome, clean solution with the help of the comments of [Gahan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7664524/gahan) and [Daniel Roseman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/104349/daniel-roseman):

```
class StatusViewSet(ModelViewSet):
permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)
serializer_class = serializers.StatusSerializer

def get_queryset(self):
    queryset = helperfunctions.getObjects(self.request.user, models.Status)
    return queryset
```

And added a router to the urlpatterns:

```
router = routers.SimpleRouter()
router.register(r'status', views.StatusViewSet, base_name='Status')

urlpatterns = router.urls
```

Thank you all very much!

Comment: Note that this does not exactly implement your desired behaviour. Besides your wanted `list` and `retrieve` view, `ModelViewSet` also implements `create`, `destroy` and `update` functionality. When implementing APIs, you should provide comprehensive and sensible endpoints. Imho, @idik provided the right and exact answer to your question.

Comment: It is clean, but as said it gives you more than you wanted - allowing to delete and mess around with the data in your database. To avoid that, you also need to set up permissions for these actions.

Comment: I actually do need all of these functionalities as well. Concerning the permissions, I'll make sure to add that. Because your answer was in fact the correct one, I'll mark it as the answer for future generations. Thank you!